# An archive with long filename inside – unarchiver hits filesystem limit and fails

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, archive

I have an unarchiver that takes in an archive name, and a directory name, and dumps all files from that archive into that directory. No other command-line options. However, someone zipped a file in the archive I am looking to decompress, with 500-ish characters in the filename, and now that program fails when it hits that file (practically all file systems have a limit of 256). What alternative do I have, short of changing the source code and recompiling the unarchiver?

I must mount something as a directory, which would take the files that the unarchiver is writing, and dump them elsewhere – possibly even as one big file. This something should not send fail messages, even if some write really did fail.

I have tried mounting a directory as a file – however, that directory must have an underlying filesystem, and then it has the same limitations as the original FS.

I have also tried using a pipe – but a pipe cannot have arguments after it (e.g. `/pipe/reallylongfilename`). Is something like this possible?

The archive is a `.zim`. I am using the `zimdump` tool from the OpenZim library.

Comment: The name length limit might come from the common kernel code, not even any filesystem-specific parts. Otherwise you could use FUSE (on Linux) to do something like you're describing. But it may just be easier to fix the archiver to do shorten extra-long names, or just binary patch the archive to make the name more sensible. I do wonder how the archive was created, though. The [list in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) doesn't have many filesystems that would support file names > 255 bytes/characters.

Comment: what is the archive format? May be possible to find another unarchiver tool that can support renaming output.

Comment: You may consider changing the title. Your real problem is the overly long filename in the archive and the title should reflect this. Compare: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/355310). The question is OK (no XY syndrome there), I'm talking about the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know this very long name then you can try to edit it inside the archive using hex editor (or `sed`?). Work with a copy in case you need to start from scratch.

Let the example filename be `very-long-filename`. Reasonable angles of attack:

- `very/long/filename`,
- `very//////filename`,
- `very0long-filename` where `0` indicates NULL character (`0x00`),
- `very00000000000000` (`0` as above).

In general it's not wise to delete characters (thus making the archive smaller). It changes important offsets inside the archive and will probably corrupt it.

I made a test with a `.zip` file. I admit my `very-long-filename` was not too long. I managed to make it shorter and maybe these methods will also work for names that *are* too long. In my test I had to edit *two fragments* of the file because every filename in `.zip` was stored *twice*.

You used the word "zipped" but didn't state clearly what your archive is. Whatever it is I hope it stores filenames in plain text and you will succeed in editing them. Good luck.

Comment: It's in the comments.  .zim file.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: It looked like there were extra characters after the filename, which signify that the filename is over-- but I figured it out.  Thanks-- I never realized that even the most compressed archives could still contain plaintext filenames...

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your feedback. It's good to know you solved the problem.

Comment: FYI ZIP format has a header (immediately) before each file/entry, _plus_ a collected clump of headers for _all_ files/entries traditionally called the 'central directory' even though it's at the end: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure